# How to find all words starting with my_str in an RDD of strings using pyspark and regex?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of strings (all in lower case) and I want to use regular expression to match or find all of the words starting with "can". How can I do this in Python?

As an example for an input like

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['canada','canpar','beauty','can'])
```

I want to have an output like

```
['canada','canpar','can']
```

which is an RDD.

Comment: I do not understand why I get a negative point for my question. could you explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With using string functions

```
filteredRDD = rdd.filter(lambda x: x.startswith('can'))
```

With using `re` module

```
import re
filteredRDD = rdd.filter(lambda x: re.compile('can').match(x))
```

You can test results by collecting contents of filteredRDD as `filteredRDD.collect()`